# Invariance of the Lebesgue integral.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

**Problem**
Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Show that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x-\frac{1}{x})dx$.

**Discussion** I know the Lebesgue integral is translation invariant (as the Lebesgue measure is), but I have never encountered the above invariance. I thought maybe if I rewrote both integrals as the measure of a set I could show both sets had the same measure, or I could use a change of variables, but nothing has worked yet. The question is a small part of a bigger problem related to fourier transforms.

Comment: if $f(x)=x,x\in[2,3]$, then they are not equal.

Comment: @gaoxinge Can you prove that they are not equal ?

Comment: @Amr $\int_2^3 xdx=2.5$ and $\int_2^3 x-\frac{1}{x}dx=2.5-ln(\frac{3}{2})$

Comment: The statement is for the integral of the function on all of $\mathbb{R}$, not restricted to a compact subset

Comment: @CurtisW We can extend $f$: $f(x)=x,x\in[2,3]$ and $f(x)=0,$otherwise

Comment: @gaoxinge I don't agree. It seems that you're function $f$ is $x1_{[2,3]}(x)$. $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x-\frac{1}{x}) dx\not= \int_2^3 x-\frac{1}{x} dx$

Comment: @gaoxinge Then you also have to change the limits in the second integral.

Comment: Oh, yes. I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us assume that $f\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ so that all of the following integrals exist.
The statement then follows by density.

Note that the function $(0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $x\mapsto x-\frac{1}{x}$ is smooth and bijective.

By a change of variables $x=y-\frac{1}{y}$ we see

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) dx &= \int_0^\infty f\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty f\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)dx+\int_0^\infty f\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)\frac{1}{x^2}dx
\end{align}$$

But by a substitution $-\frac{1}{x}=y$ in the last integral we see that

$$\int_0^\infty f\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)\frac{1}{x^2} dx=\int_{-\infty}^0 f\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)dx$$

which gives the desired identity.

Comment: Sorry, but what is the difference between change of variables and substitution here ?

Comment: There is none @derivative.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give another solution (well, mostly the same, but presented in a different light). It is longer, but it does not rely on any trick. Let $T(x) := x-1/x$. Remark that the equation $T(x) = y$ has exactly two solutions, given by :

$$\frac{y \pm \sqrt{4+y^2}}{2}.$$

Or, another fancy way to state this fact is that $T^{-1}$ has two branches. I'll denote them by $T_-^{-1}$ and $T_+^{-1}$, with the corresponding sign in the formula above. Note that $T \circ T_-^{-1} = T \circ T_+^{-1} = id$ on $\mathbb{R}^*$, while $T_-^{-1} \circ T = id$ on $\mathbb{R}_-^*$ and $T_+^{-1} \circ T = id$ on $\mathbb{R}_+^*$.

Then I just use (formally) the change of variables $y := T(x)$.

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(T(x)) dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}_-^*} \frac{f}{|T'|\circ T_-^{-1}}(T(x)) |T'(x)| dx + \int_{\mathbb{R}_+^*} \frac{f}{|T'|\circ T_+^{-1}}(T(x)) |T'|(x) dx,$$

whence:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(T(x)) dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \sum_{\pm} \frac{1}{|T'|\circ T_\pm^{-1}}(y) f(y) dy.$$

This formula generalizes the change of variable to transformations which are not bijections. All we need to prove is that:

$$\sum_{\pm} \frac{1}{|T'|\circ T_\pm^{-1}} \equiv 1.$$

At this point, everything is explicit and you only need to check that this condition holds. It is tedious, but it does not require any insight. For the sake of completeness, I'll give a proof with relatively few computations.

Note that $T' (x) = 1+x^{-2}$, so that:

$$\frac{1}{|T'|\circ T_\pm^{-1}} = \frac{1}{1+ \frac{1}{(T_\pm^{-1})^2}} = \frac{(T_\pm^{-1})^2}{1+ (T_\pm^{-1})^2}.$$

I'll now write $x_\pm$ instead of $T_\pm^{-1} (y)$. Note that $x_\pm$ are the solution to the quadratic equation $x^2 -yx-1 = 0$, so that $x_- x_+ = -1$ and $(x_- x_+)^2 = 1$. Then:

$$\sum_{\pm} \frac{1}{|T'|\circ T_\pm^{-1}} = \sum_{\pm} \frac{x_\pm^2}{1+ x_\pm^2} = \frac{x_-^2+2 (x_- x_+)^2+x_+^2}{1+ x_-^2 + x_+^2 + (x_- x_+)^2} 
= \frac{2+x_-^2+x_+^2}{2+ x_-^2 + x_+^2} = 1.$$

Comment: Do you have a reference for that change of variables that doesn't need bijections?

Comment: @Your Ad Here: strangely, it is quite hard to found at an elementary level. The idea comes from transfer operators (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_operator). Here, the "auxiliary function" is the inverse of the Jacobian, and the underlying (here, Lebesgue) measure is invariant if and only if $\mathcal{L}1 = 1$.